# VBA array (ReDim Preserve & Indexing)

Tags: vba

As a beginner of VBA, I am confused with the following issue:

```
Dim DynArray() As Double 
ReDim DynArray(0 To 0)
DynArray(0) = 100
ReDim Preserve DynArray(5 To 5)  'subscript out of range
DynArray(5) = 100
```

why it doesn't work? and how to change the upper bound and/or lower bound of an array in VBA while retaining the values of the original array?
Thank you.

Comment: why does your title say C++ when the question is all about vba?

Comment: type wrong name.... but do not know how to modify after submitted...

Comment: Sorry to be picky... but now it says `Resim` in the title instead of `ReDim`. Can you fix that too?

Comment: Given what @Leviathan already explained, maybe you can explain your goal since from your code it doesn't seem necessary to change the lower bound

Comment: As far as I know the lower bound or any VBA array can only be 0 or 1: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266179(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: @Ralph: That's only true for the `Option Base` statement that globally (for that module) defines the *default* lower bound of an array so you can declare an array with `Dim a(5)` with the 5 being the upper bound and the lower bound being 0 or whatever you set `Option Base` to. To whatever that is set, you can always declare your array explicitly with another lower bound (as the OP did), arbitrarily high.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251578.aspx) states that

> when you use Preserve, you can change the size of the array only by
>   changing the upper bound; changing the lower bound causes an error.

Meaning: you can only do

```
ReDim Preserve DynArray(0 To 5)
```

Comment: Good short answer. I have added another answer just to add a few details.

Comment: Thank you very much! It's helpful

Comment: You can upvote any answer that you find helpful by clicking the arrows on the left. In addition, you can mark the answer that answers your question best as the accepted answer. That signals to other readers that this answer solved your problem. It also provides *reputation* to the answerer and even a bit to yourself. You can read https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation if you want to know more about what reputation on StackOverflow is and how it works.

Answer (score 1):

*The above answer is correct but I just wanted to add a few details.*

> If you use the **Preserve keyword**, you can ***resize only the last array
>   dimension and you can't change the number of dimensions at all***. For
>   example, if your array has only one dimension, you can resize that
>   dimension because it is the last and only dimension. However, if your
>   array has two or more dimensions, you can change the size of only the
>   last dimension and still preserve the contents of the array. The
>   following example shows how you can increase the size of the last
>   dimension of a dynamic array without erasing any existing data
>   contained in the array.

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251578.aspx) :

This example uses the ReDim statement to allocate and reallocate storage space for dynamic-array variables. It assumes the Option Base is 1.

```
Dim MyArray() As Integer ' Declare dynamic array. 
Redim MyArray(5) ' Allocate 5 elements. 
For I = 1 To 5 ' Loop 5 times. 
 MyArray(I) = I ' Initialize array. 
Next I
```

The next statement resizes the array and erases the elements.

```
Redim MyArray(10) ' Resize to 10 elements. 
For I = 1 To 10 ' Loop 10 times. 
 MyArray(I) = I ' Initialize array. 
Next I
```

The following statement resizes the array but does not erase elements.

```
                  Redim Preserve MyArray(15) ' Resize to 15 elements.
```

So your mistake : `ReDim Preserve DynArray(5 To 5)` where you changed the lower bound.